# Sublime Text and JSX code format within JS file

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3, jsx, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

With Sublime Text, what is the best plugin for JSX code formatting ?
Also, specifically, if the JSX code is written inside .js file (instead of .jsx file), what do we need to do to handle the formatting inside JS file ?

Comment: I think [babel-sublime](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime) should do the job. But I haven't yet tried it.

Comment: Actually, writing it inside .js is a semantic mistake because JSX isn't valid JS in any specification but an extension over it.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text is a great editor. It took me a while to work out the correct configuration but now it's up and running I really appreciate its light feel (few distractions from the actual code), its flexibility and speed.

I use the [JSCustom package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JSCustom) for code highlighting.

There's nothing extra that you need for the JSX highlighting, it's included in JSCustom.